# how to use animation xml file into onTouchEvent method

Tags: android, android-animation

i have an animation called moving image.in that image moves all directions and when i click on image it will change the direction for that i am creating file called animation.xml. so i have to use that xml file into my onTouchEvent,but i am unable do that so please help me.

```
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xStart = (int) event.getX();
                yStart = (int) event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                xEnd = (int) event.getX();
                yEnd = (int) event.getY();
                break;
            }
            if(xStart >= x && yStart >= y && xEnd <= (x+ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) && yEnd <= (y+ball.getBitmap().getHeight())){


                Log.i("MainActivity","AnimatedView  Clicked................");
            }

            return false;
        }
```

animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
  android:duration="4000"
  android:fromXDelta="0%p"
  android:toXDelta="0%p"
  android:toYDelta="-73%p" 
  android:fromYDelta="-36%p"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
  android:repeatMode="restart"

  />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) instead onTouchListener.
2. To enable animation from resources you have to use [`View.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.animation));`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View)

So finally it looks that:

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            myView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
        }
    });
```